# Prioritize network adapter initialization on startup

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8.1, boot, network-adapter

**TL;DR**: How to make the network adapter connect earlier/faster?

When I start up the OS (Win 8.1) from either Hibernation or from a full restart my network adapter won't connect as fast as I'd like it to connect. It seems like the network adapter or windows itself is "lagging" behind the actual startup sequence, making the adapter to connect when it's already "too late" for great user experience.

Windows notification area shows the ["no-connection"-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJkMz.jpg) for about 5-10 seconds meanwhile the computer itself is already ready to be used but just can't connect to the network just yet.

I've already tried searching with Google, but the results were talking about prioritizing wired connection over wireless (vice versa), and that's not what I'm looking for.

So how can I make the **network adapter to connect earlier/faster** without creating any security issues? Is it something already known related to the software/drivers or hardware?
I don't have a WLAN card attached and everything is working otherwise just great regarding network connectivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **changing all of my CAT5e cables to CAT6** and replacing a 10m (32f) cable to a 1.5m (5f) the connection is established immediately on boot, so the problem doesn't exist anymore.